# Get Minimum value from Second Table in Laravel using relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables

1. Product List

> id |  name       | user_id

```
  1     Product 1    10  
  2     Product 2    15
```

2. Price

> id | list_id | price | type

```
1    1        250      1
2    2        350      2
3    1        500      1
4    2        600      2
```

Product listing table contain listing details and it is associated with the price table now i want to get the all the products and an extra field minimum price with every list. for eg. if i have product 1 listing then there i want to add extra field which extract minimum price 250 from price.

```
Listing::select('*')->whereHas('PriceVal', function($q) use($country) {
                        $q->where('Type','1');
                       })
                      ->selectRaw("count(*) as total")
                      ->where(['user_id' => $userId])->with('PriceVal')
                      ->get();
```

> Relation:

```
 public function PriceVal()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Price', 'id', 'list_id');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [advanced sub query](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#advanced-subqueries):

the main idea is to add select the min price from the related table:

```
return Listing::addSelect(['minimum_price' => Price::select('price')
    ->whereColumn('prices.list_id', 'product_lists.id')
    ->orderBy('price', 'asc')
    ->limit(1)
])->whereHas('PriceVal', function($q) use($country) {
                        $q->where('Type','1');
                       })->where(['user_id' => $userId])->get();
```

you can add the   `$q->where('Type','1')` inside the add select section if you want to get only the min price with type =1